# C# class backward compatibility

Tags: c#, backwards-compatibility

I have a NuGet package that is been used by some projects internally. Now, while refactoring the project, I found several classes that were named inappropriately. I want to know if there is any way in C# change the class names and not break anything.

Comment: Increment the package's major version number and document breaking changes. That is about all you can do.

Comment: Provide two names, make the old one deprecated and after few major releases, delete old names.

Comment: @Zereges should post that as an answer :)

Comment: @Zereges - I don't see how that would work. You would have to change all public facing interfaces that use these types as parameters and add copy functionality to copy state between types. It could be a real PITA to get this right depending on what is changing. Here is a simple example: `void Update(Kustomer userInfo)` and `Kustomer` should now be `Customer` which means add a new type but also a new method everywhere it is used including internally...

Comment: @Igor Does providing `using Kustomer = Customer` alias work in that case?

Comment: @Zereges - no, that is a type alias specific to a code file which is not the same thing as renaming an existing public facing type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to rename identifiers without breaking other people code. The best thing you can do is to leave `clAssNaME` identifier, provide new `ClassName` and mark `clAssNaME` as deprecated. Publish new release with documented and highlighted changelog.

When you're confident enough that most people managed to *fix* their code, delete the `clAssNaME`.

Answer (score 1):

What you do depends on the extent of the changes. If the types with the changed names are not simple types (ie. have a lot of behavior) or are used throughout your package it can be very difficult to create a copy of the type because you also have to ensure the code can use either type (for a while anyways).

A simpler solution might be to branch your package and increment the major version number in the new branch. In the "new" branch: Update the type names, document the breaking changes, and push a release as a new version. You can then maintain both branches until you see fit to stop work on the "older" branch. In the "older" branch you can also mark types as deprecated with a warning that in the future version they will have a changed name.